# How to get data from a database and update it in app in android?

Tags: android, database, web-services, parsing

Ok i need my app to retrieve data from a DB and display it in my app, i know this can be done using XML/JSON parsing but the data is to be updated almost daily so updating XML file wont be a possibility. The server uses SQL DB, so is there any other way other than Parsing data from it? I have heard about web service getting data n returning it to the app but in my case will it work? Will ibe able to retrieve specific data i need from the server?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need to create one web service and deploy it on your server which query the database and return the response in JSON/XML format and then parse that response and update your app's data. That's the straight simple way.

---

As you said you need to do this daily, you can think of creating a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for the task and might be you can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) too.

Comment: +1 but Question contain "The server uses SQL DB, so is there any other way other than Parsing data from it?"

Comment: ha ha ha... I dont know what is SQL DB and Web Servers...So can't even think on it.. @PareshMayani for that will have to contact one good experienced web developer I guess...or I guess we should edit the question and add tag SQL or something...what you say.!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can refer this link
[Android (Java) Simple Send and recieve with Server - Fast Setup Challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983761/android-java-simple-send-and-recieve-with-server-fast-setup-challenge)

[Sending and receiving data from a web service using android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854600/sending-and-receiving-data-from-a-web-service-using-android?lq=1)

[simple client server communication in android](http://osamashabrez.com/simple-client-server-communication-in-android/)